# iPhone Animation of UIImageView for any angle?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, core-animation

Please help regarding an iPhone animation.

I have an `UIImageView` and I want to animate this from the right side only on a particular angle. Afterwards, I want to return it to the previous state.

Let's say my `UIImageView` name is `GunImage` with a width and height of `100` and `50` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(yourAngle*(3.14/180));
```

Comment: i will check it and then tell u about it